# If the entry is made with the same ID, data need to be submitted with suffix. For e.g. if ID no. 001 is submitted again, data must saved as '001/Rev'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using checkbox on the sheet to trigger the script such that data in the dropdown get saved to the neighboring sheet. Requirement is if the entry is done of the same SRF number, then it needs to be saved with the suffix.
For E.g. if SRF No 'AS/SRF-004' is submitted again, it should save as 'AS/SRF-004/Rev' and if repeats again then 'AS/SRF-004/Rev-2' and so on.

Don't know whether it is possible or silly for me to ask this question.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? For example, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. I apologize for my poor English skill again. By the way, what is `Attaching the Ss link for more clarity.`?

Comment: Hello, Let's start with the example only. Attaching the Ss link for more clarity. Suppose I have assigned 'AS/SRF-001' to anyone, the assigned data is getting saved at the neighboring sheet name "Helper(Assign Status-from down)".
If i assign the same 'AS/SRF-001' to someone, the entry which saves on the neighboring sheet should have 'AS/SRF-001/REV-01' in the Revision Column.
SS Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RiLjepEpYhkhCTgMHxrTxSI7GWloj954C4dsq0jT11E/edit?usp=sharing

Sorry, previous comment got submitted partially, coz of internet issue.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, by guessing your goal, I proposed the modified script of your script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, I found your current script. Although this is hidded in your question, I thought that you might want to use this script. So in this answer, I would like to propose to modify your current script.

From your question and your reply, I understood your goal is as follows.

- When the values of "C6" and "C8" are set and the checkbox is checked in "SRF Allotment" sheet, you want to put the values to the columns "A" and "B" of "Helper(Assign Status-from down)" sheet. At that time, you want to check the number of value of "C6" in the column "A" and put the value of `/REV-#` as the suffix.
- You want to achieve this by modifying your current script.

If my understanding of your goal is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh1 = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.range;
  if (sh1.getName() == 'SRF Allotment' && r.getA1Notation() == 'C9' && r.getValue() === true) {
    var sh2 = e.source.getSheetByName('Helper(Assign Status-from down)');
    var v = r.offset(-3, 0).getValue();
    var n = sh2.getRange("A2:A" + sh2.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(v).matchEntireCell(true).findAll().length;
    var values = [v, r.offset(-1, 0).getValue(), null, null, `${v}/REV-${n + 1}`];
    sh2.appendRow(values);
    r.uncheck();
    e.source.getSheetByName('SRF Allotment').getRangeList(["C6", "C8"]).clearContent();
  }
}
```

- In this modification, the value of "C6" of "SRF Allotment" sheet is searched from the column "A" of `Helper(Assign Status-from down)`. Using this result, the suffix is added like `${v}/REV-${n + 1}`. I used TextFinder for searching the value.

#### Note:

- In your question, it seems that you want to use `AS/SRF-004/Rev-2`. On the other hand, in your reply, it seems that you want to use `AS/SRF-004/Rev` and `AS/SRF-001/REV-01`. From this situation, I couldn't understand your actual suffix. So I used `${v}/REV-${n + 1}`. If this was not your expected result, please modify it to your expected one.

#### Reference:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)

Comment: It is working great. @Tanaike just wanted to know if the below mentioned is possible by any means.

-In this sheet, Data from specific cell(C6) is getting checked and transported to another sheet i.e. Helper Sheet with Suffix 'Rev-01'. Suppose if I link google form to sheet 1 to take the entry, then is it possible to check every newly received entry to be transported to Sheet 2 with the incremental Suffix(as it was happening before).
For E.g. If New Entry received is SRF-001 then it should check on neighboring sheet col A and .....(rest all same as before)

Comment: For E.g. If New Entry received via google form is for SRF-001(Col 1) then it should check on neighboring sheet Col A(where all data will already be available) and insert SRF-001/Rev-1(in Col 3)

Comment: @Asif Sheikh Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But in this case, can you post it as a new question by including more information. Because I cannot correctly understand your new question from your reply. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Thanks for the revert.
Pls check 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71763245/to-check-the-srf-number-in-the-neighboring-sheet-and-allot-revision-number
Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @Asif Sheikh Thank you for replying. I will check it.